# Google login error On Windows 10 UAP application

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, windows-10, google-signin

I am having this weird issue on Windows 10, I am using the same code as on my Windows 8.1 application but i am unable to authenticate to Google Login it goes right through.

what am I doing wrong?

```
public async Task<string> LogIntoGoogle()
        {
            try
            {
               credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                    new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/client_secrets.json"),
                    new[] { "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.profile.emails.read" },
                    "user",
                    CancellationToken.None);

                return credential.Token.AccessToken;

            }
            catch (Exception exe)
            {

                var data = exe;
            }
            return "";
        }
```

Edit:  looks like I only have 2 google references:

[image]

Edit2: yes I was missing the Google.Api.Core reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure that you have all of the correct references? for the Google login? you should have 3.

Update: looks like you are missing Google.Api.Core reference